# Add a field to the taxonomy editor?

Tags: theme-development, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to add an additional image field to WooCommerce Product Taxonomy Admin page as part of my theme.  It works fine by modifying the existing class within the plugin, but it will be replaced when Woo Themes updates it.

The class is included in class-wc-admin.php and then called directly from within the class-wc-admin-taxonomies.php file.  I don't see any hook to modify the functionality.

Any ideas on how to replace the existing WC_Admin_Taxonomies class without breaking when I upgrade?

Screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://iadesigngroup.com/images/screenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Woocommerce specific, just the regular WordPress term edit screen. So you can use the normal action `{$taxonomyname}_edit_form_fields`.

Example:

```php
add_action( "product_cat_edit_form_fields", function() {
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">Additional image</th>
        <td>Some image upload code …</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}, 2000 );
```

Comment: Yep, I realized how dumb of a question that was when it clicked. Thanks for the great answer!